# ASP.NET / Linq - How do you escape HTML characters in a linq query?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have this Linq query:

```
from depot in Depots
where depot.DepotTypeId == id
select new
{
DepotId = depot.DepotId,
GpsLatitude = depot.GpsLatitude,
GpsLongitude = depot.GpsLongitude,
locationName = depot.DepotName
}
```

Which works just fine, but the locationName can contain characters like ' and ". This is bad, as I need that variable in an HTML5 data attribute. Extra characters break my HTML syntax. So I tried this:

```
locationName = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(depot.DepotName)
```

But this returns the error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String
>   HtmlEncode(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be
>   translated into a store expression.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You will need to return the data and THEN encode it. You can't do it as part of Linq to Entities. Linq to Entities has a lot of limitation due to what can be translated to SQL.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you're sort of doing formatting (encoding) stuff in or close to your domain objects. I don't think this is good. Rather than suggesting an actual answer, I would suggest that you put off encoding until it's time to render the value in the page. Additional benefits from this approach (obviously) include that you can then use the domain object for other stuff than feeding a particular "view".

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Oskar and James, I will encode it on the client's side using JavaScript's encodeURIComponent() method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main issue here is that `HtmlEncode` method cannot be translated into SQL, what you need to do to fix it is to evaluate the LINQ query (i.e. pull the data from database) before selecting:

```
Depots
    .Where(d => d.DepotTypeId == id)
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(d => new {
        DepotId = d.DepotId,
        GpsLatitude = d.GpsLatitude,
        GpsLongitude = d.GpsLongitude,
        LocationName = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(d.DepotName)
    });
```

Comment: how do i do this without having an id to search for, meaning i just want to do this for all elements

Comment: I forgot to mark this as an answer, it only took me near 8 years! Thanks.